# Is there an injective ring homomorphism from $\Bbb R \oplus \Bbb R$ to $C(\Bbb R)$?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, functions, ring-theory, continuity

True or False:

> There exists injective ring homomorphism from $\Bbb R \oplus \Bbb R$ to $C(\Bbb R)$, where $C(\Bbb R)$ is the set of continuous functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$.

I was trying to think that I can exploit the fact $\Bbb R \oplus \Bbb R$ is not an integral domain but we can't because $(1,0) \to f$ and $(0,1) \to g$ both non zero continuous function s.t their product is zero.

Comment: $\Bbb R \oplus \Bbb R$ has four idempotents, and $C(\mathbb R)$ only two, so the answer is negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** In the ring $\Bbb{R}\oplus\Bbb{R}$ you have $(1,0)\times(0,1)=0$ and $(1,0)+(0,1)=1$.

---

**Details:** Let $f$ and $g$ denote the images of $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ in $C(\Bbb{R})$, respectively. Then $fg=0$ and $f+g=1$, so $g=1-f$, meaning that
$$0=fg=f(1-f)=f-f^2.$$
It follows that $f=f^2$, and so $f(x)\in\{0,1\}$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$. Because $f$ is continuous we have either $f\equiv0$ or $f\equiv1$. But the elements $0,1\in R$ are already mapped to the functions $0,1\in C(\Bbb{R})$. This shows that there is no injective ring homomorphism from $\Bbb{R}\oplus\Bbb{R}$ to $C(\Bbb{R})$.

Comment: Does injective ring homos send $1$ to $1$?

Comment: Not sure what the first operation means: the can be two continuous non-zero functions whose multiplication is zero.

Comment: To expand on the answer, we get from this that $(1, 0), (0, 1)$ must correspond to $1, 0$ (as functions of $C(R)$) and this contradicts injectivity.

Comment: Can you expand a bit more? How do you exploit the continuity using that they sum to $1$?

Comment: Okay, try giving three more lines/hints and I will let you know whether I can take from there or not!

Comment: There's not a lot of topology here, just the fact that image of connected set via continuous function is connected.

Comment: Yeah, I know this fact then how do you use it?

Comment: Thanks, accepted it.

Comment: @Servaes I think I can see your point now.